# ImageView Scrolling along with the tableview

Tags: iphone

In my application,i created an imageview on the above the tabbar.I want to display some images here for displaying some adds there.
What my actual problem is...i added this on my table view and whenever i am scrolling the table view ,my imageview is also scrolling.Please help me in this

Thanks in advance.Here is my code

```
UIImageView *currentLocationImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
 NSURL *url1 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://imgsrv.995themountain.com/image/kqmt2/UserFiles/Image/SiteGraphics/MTNVideos360x80.jpg"];
 UIImage *img1 = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url1]]; 
 NSURL *url2 = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://download.xbox.com/content/images/35f6c527-fb73-40d3-bcb9-bdea2680bc03/1033/banner.png"];
 UIImage *img2 = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url2]]; 

 NSArray *images = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:img1, img2, nil];
 [currentLocationImageView setAnimationImages:images];
 [currentLocationImageView setAnimationRepeatCount:0];
 [currentLocationImageView setAnimationDuration:5.0];
 currentLocationImageView.frame = CGRectMake(0.0, 340.0, 320.0, 30.0);
 //self.tableView.tableFooterView = currentLocationImageView; 
 [currentLocationImageView startAnimating];
 [self.view addSubview:currentLocationImageView];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing more code, it looks as though you may be using a `UITableViewController` instead of a `UIViewController`. The difference between the two is important in the case of your last line `[self.view addSubview:currentLocationImageView]`. What that does in a `UIViewController` is adds it to the view that would be containing the tableview and the imageview. However, in a `UITableViewController` the `self.view` property holds the tableview itself, therefor, it ads your image view as a subview of the tableview, subjecting it to the tableview's scrolling behaviour.

What you can do is change from using a UITableViewController (probably going to be trivial for your application, but may be less than trivial depending on why you opted to use it in the first place); and you'll also need to explicitly create the tableview, and add it to the backing view of the `UIViewController` subclass you're writing—akin to how you're adding the imageview above.

Hope this helps.